# How to create a binary tree hierarchy given a list of elements as its leaves

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I am trying to build a binary tree hierarchy given numerical elements serving for its leaves (last level of the tree to build). From the leaves I want to randomly create a name for the higher level of the hierarchy and assigning it to the children elements. For example: if the elements inputted are `0,1,2,3` then I would like to create firstly 4 elements (say by random giving them a label composed of a letter and a number) then for the second level (iteration) I assign each of 0,1 to a random name label (e.g. `b1`) and `2,3` to another label (`b2`) then for the third level I assign a parent label to each of `b1` and `b2` as `c1`.

An illustation of the example is the following tree:

[image: hiearchy binary tree example]

For this I use numpy's `array_split()` to get the chunks of arrays based on the iteration needs.
for example to get the first iteration arrays I use `np.array_split(input, (input.size // k))` where `k` is an even number. In order to assign a parent node to the children the array range should enclose the children's. For example to assign the parent node with label `a1` to children `b1` and `b2` with range respectively [0,1] and [2,3], the parent should have the range [0,3].

All is fine until a certain iteration (k=4) returns parent with range [0,8] which is overlapping to children ranges and therefore cannot be their parent.

My question is how to evenly partition such arrays in a binary way and create such binary tree so that to obtain for k=4 the first range to be [0,7] instead of [0,8]?

My code is the following:

```
import string
import random
import numpy as np
def generate_numbers_list_until_number(stop_number) -> np.ndarray:
    if str(stop_number).isnumeric():
        return np.arange(stop_number)  
    else:
        raise TypeError("Input should be a number!")
def generate_node_label():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) + str(random.randint(0, 10))
def main():
    data=generate_numbers_list_until_number(100)
    k=1
    hierarchies = []
    cells_arrays=np.array_split(data, (data.size // k))
    print(cells_arrays)
    used_node_hierarchy_name=[]
    node_hierarchy_name = [generate_node_label() for _ in  range(0,len(cells_arrays))]
    used_node_hierarchy_name.extend(node_hierarchy_name)
    while len(node_hierarchy_name)>1:
        k=(k*2)
        #bug here in the following line
        cells_arrays=list(map(lambda x:[x[0],x[-1]],np.array_split(data, (data.size // k) )))
        print(cells_arrays)
        node_hierarchy_name=[]
        #node hierarchy names should not be redundant in another level
        for _ in  range(0,len(cells_arrays)):
            node_name = generate_node_label() 
            while node_name in used_node_hierarchy_name:
                node_name = generate_node_label()
            node_hierarchy_name.append(node_name)
            used_node_hierarchy_name.extend(node_hierarchy_name)
        print(used_node_hierarchy_name)
        hierarchies.append(list(zip(node_hierarchy_name,cells_arrays)))
```